# Android studio with kotlin: Room Database Query using 2 parameters for order

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Im fairly new to android proggraming and would like help to a question I couldn't find on the site.
I'm using ItemDao to Query a room database.

for simplicity, lets say that my room database class got this parameters:
class Person{
first name,
last name,
age,
height,
etc...

I if I want to get list of persons ordered by age I will use:

```
    @Query("SELECT * from personTable ORDER by age ASC")
    fun readAllPersonOrderedByAge(): LiveData<List<Person>>
```

how can I query this database by using main order parameter and secondery one (lets say by age (main) and height (scondary) if age is the same?

Thanks,
Tal

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the field with a comma:

```
@Query("SELECT * from personTable ORDER by age ASC, height DESC")
```

[Documentation](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-order-by/)

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add more columns in the order you want them to appear.

For example, in your case (first age, second height):

```
@Query("SELECT * from personTable ORDER by age, height ASC")
    fun readAllPersonOrderedByAge(): LiveData<List<Person>>
```

Comment: For mor info about SQL queries, you can check an oficial web like W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp